# linear regression problems with statsmodel

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, regression, statsmodels

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
   broker-value-current  broker-value-prior      consensus-after  
                 590.00              510.00              462.55   
                  32.74               31.98               30.72   
                  33.00               30.00               30.04 

           pctch_broker      pctch_consensus    pctch_frstrec_eps 
              15.686275             1.599051             1.421657   
               2.376485             0.195695           -82.098455   
              10.000000             0.805369           -82.098455  

      pctch_frstrec_rev  
               1.243782  
              -1.258936  
              -1.258936
```

Where the last few columns were created with:

```
 data['pctch_broker'] = ((data['broker-value-current']-data['broker-value-prior'])/data['broker-value-prior'])*100
 data['pctch_consensus'] = ((data['consensus-after']-data['consensus-before'])/data['consensus-before'])*100
 data['pctch_frstrec_eps'] = ((data['frstrec_eps_announced']-data['frstrec_eps_forecast'])/data['frstrec_eps_forecast'])*100
 data['pctch_frstrec_rev'] = ((data['frstrec_rev_announced']-data['frstrec_rev_forecast'])/data['frstrec_rev_forecast'])*100
```

I also clear NA with this line:

```
cleaned_data = data.dropna()
```

When using scipy stats:

```
 import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
```

However when I try to regress 'pctch_consensus' or 'pctch_broker' as the independent variable with 'pctch_frstrec_rev' or 'pctch_frstrec_eps' as the dependent variable with this code:

```
 reg1 = sm.ols(formula="pctch_consensus ~ pctch_frstrec_rev", data=cleaned_data).fit()
```

I receive this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater return (S > tol).sum(axis=-1)
```

Comment: whoops, thanks I updated the question, yeah I have this line in my imports as well: import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurring because there are infinities in your dataframe. You created these infinities possibly by dividing by zero when creating your new variables.

This should fix it:

```
cleaned_data = data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```